# Wi-Fi speed: Wi-Fi pretty much nonexistent while Ethernet works perfectly fine

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, ethernet, wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge

Over the last couple months, my Wi-Fi speed turned from perfectly fine to *ridiculously* slow. I never had amazing Internet, but it worked and was fast enough.

It doesn't even matter *where* I am – right next to the router, above it, underneath it – it stays just as bad.

It works perfectly fine using Ethernet, though. I don't really mind using Ethernet on my desktop, but it's pretty annoying on my laptop and practically impossible on my phone.

Any ideas why that may be and how to fix it?

Comment: Try a different radio channel in the router settings, also when was the last time you restarted the router? If all else fails try a different router.

Comment: In order to help you, we will need the Router Model, the Laptop Make and Model.  Also, are you using 5GHz or 2.4GHz?